# Sending an array of custom data. It's not the same what I've sent that what I've received

Tags: c++, sockets

I've got an object defined as follow:

```
struct myData{
  int32_t* myVector;
  double myValue;
}
```

`myVector` is not defined when I compile because it depends on a file, but when I send my data it is defined. I want to send to my server an array of myData, so I have this code:

```
ssize_t Send(int fd, const myData message[], const int num, const int elementsOnMyVector){
  ssize_t size = num*(sizeof(myValue) + elementsOnMyVector*sizeof(message[0].myVector[0]));
  char mes[size] = "";

  int ptr = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < elementsOnMyVector; j++){
      int32_t data = htonl(message[i].myVector[j]);
      memcpy(&mes[ptr], &data, sizeof(data));
      ptr += sizeof(data);
    }
    memcpy(&mes[ptr], &(message[i].myValue), sizeof(message[i].myValue));
    ptr += sizeof(message[i].myValue);
  }
  ssize_t num_bytes = send(fd, message, size, 0);
  return num_bytes;
}
```

I `std::cout << std::hex << mes << ",";` and it seems that the message is send correctly. But in the server when I do a recv the data that I recieved is totally different (checked before processing it). At the moment the server does the recv it knows how big `myData[]` would be so I read exactly the same amount of bytes that I've sent. I don't know what else try.
The code of the recv:

```
ssize_t Recv(int fd, myData*& buffer, const int num, const int elementsOnMyVector){
  ssize_t size = num*(sizeof(myValue) + elementsOnMyVector*sizeof(message[0].myVector[0]));
  char bufferAux[size];
  bzero(bufferAux, size);

  int num_bytes = recv(fd, bufferAux, size, 0);

  if(num_bytes == size){
    buffer = new individuo[num];
    int ptr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
      buffer[i].myVector = new int32_t[elementsOnMyVector];
      for(int j = 0; j < elementsOnMyVector; j++){
        memcpy(&(buffer[i].myVector[j]), &(bufferAux[ptr]), sizeof(int32_t));
        buffer[i].myVector[j] = ntohl(buffer[i].myVector[j]);
        ptr += sizeof(int32_t);
      }
      memcpy(&(buffer[i].myValue), &(bufferAux[ptr]), sizeof(double));
      ptr += sizeof(double);
    }
  }
  return num_bytes;
}
```

All my executions have been in my local computer using 127.0.0.1 as address and 32000 as port.

Comment: How do the sent and received data differ? How do you set up the sockets on sending and receiving side?

Comment: I send data, and when I receive it, it is not the same that I've sent

Comment: @DanielBenedí `char mes[size] = "";` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by constant, compile-time expressions, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.  In addition, if you're sending `myData`, it contains a pointer value.  You will get garbage when sending such a structure due to the pointer value.  You need to properly serialize the data.

Comment: I understood that. I was asking for more details. Do you have example data of what you send and receive?

Comment: Yes, of course. Each comma is one byte:
Sender:
0,0,0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,a,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,b,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,5,1b,bb,fb,b6,cf,fd7,32,3f

Formated: myVector = [5,7,6,8,10,1,2,11,3,0,9,4,5] -- myValue = 0.000287522


Receiver:
c0,f0,35,f8a,8a,55,0,0,1b,bb,fb,b6,cf,d7,32,3f,90,f0,35,8a,8a,55,0,0,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,a,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0

Comment: `send(fd, message, size, 0)` -> `send(fd, mes, size, 0)`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik This was the solution. Thank you very very much. I've been trying things like five hours.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I undestand. Is it a very important problem? I mean, will it give me problems in futute?

Comment: @DanielBenedí `char mes[size] = "";` will be a problem if you try use a compiler that does not support it, or if `size` is large enough to cause a stack overflow.  You should avoid it, since there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preparing the data in `mes` but you are sending `message`.

Change:

`send(fd, message, size, 0)` -> `send(fd, mes, size, 0)`